# Python error with socket. Ntohl()

Tags: python, sockets

I'm having an issue with the `socket.ntohl()` function, on some hosts.  It is repeatable on all similar hosts; 32bit machines with Python 2.4.2.

```
>>> socket.ntohl(16777215)
-256
```

However the reverse seems to work fine -

```
>>> socket.htonl(4294967040)
16777215
```

Reading [the docs](http://docs.python.org/release/2.4.2/lib/module-socket.html), It doesn't mention any limitations or warnings. Is this a bug in the Novell version of this old package? They are all Suse 9 machines :(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In older 32-bit Python versions, `int` was limited to a signed 32-bit number.  16777215 = 0x00FFFFFF and -256 in 32-bit 2s complement is 0xFFFFFF00.

It works correctly in Python 2.7 by upgrading the value to a long:

```
>>> socket.ntohl(16777215)
4294967040L
>>> hex(4294967040)
'0xffffff00L'
```

#### Edit:

Python 2.4 was the first version to unify `int` and `long` so what you see might be considered a bug that has been fixed by 2.7.

Looks like this [issue](http://bugs.python.org/issue1619659) fixed it.

Comment: Yeah, I developed in 2.7- found it in testing on 2.4. Thanks