# Using Python to write a mix of integer and floating point numbers to a binary file read by a code in C

Tags: python, c, binaryfiles

I have code in C which reads data from a file in a binary format:

```c
FILE *file;
int int_var;
double double_var;
file = fopen("file.dat", "r");
fread(&int_var, sizeof(int), 1, file);
fread(&double_var, sizeof(double), 1, file);
```

The above is a simplified but accurate version of the actual code. I have no choice over this code or the format of this file.

The data being read in C is produced using Python code. How do I write this data to a file in the same binary format? I looked into bytes and bytearrays, but they seem to only work with integers and strings. I need something like:

```py
f = open('file.dat', 'wb')
f.write(5)
f.write(5.0)
f.close()
```

that will work with the above C code.

Comment: You need to know endianness and floating-point format used both in Python (which you may need to tweak) and in your C implementation.

Comment: you're going to need https://docs.python.org/3/library/struct.html#struct.pack

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11541944/behavior-of-ntohl-and-htonl-different-between-python-and-c

Comment: basically what others are saying is you should convert the numbers to byte-arrays first with a known number of bytes and endian before writing them to the file, to make reading them possible, as python has a very unique (and hard to predict) method of handling numbers.

Comment: the documentation I found for byte-arrays only discusses how to convert between that and integers or strings, whereas I also need to handle floating point numbers. looking at the struct pack right now, thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned in a comment, you need the [`struct` library](https://docs.python.org/3/library/struct.html):

Creating `file.dat` with

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python3                                                                                                                                                                                                                           
import struct
with open('file.dat', 'wb') as f:
    f.write(struct.pack('=id', 1, 5.0))
```

and then reading it with

```c
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {
  int int_var;
  double double_var;

  FILE *file = fopen("file.dat", "rb");
  if (!file) {
    fprintf(stderr, "couldn't open file.dat!\n");
    return 1;
  }

  if (fread(&int_var, sizeof(int), 1, file) != 1) {
    fprintf(stderr, "failed to read int!\n");
    return 1;
  }

  if (fread(&double_var, sizeof(double), 1, file) != 1) {
    fprintf(stderr, "failed to read double!\n");
    return 1;
  }

  printf("int = %d\ndouble = %f\n", int_var, double_var);

  fclose(file);
  return 0;
}
```

will output

```
int = 1
double = 5.000000
```

Note the `=` in the pack format definition; that tells python not to add alignment padding bytes like you'd get in a C structure like

```c
struct foo {
  int int_var;
  double double_Var;
};
```

Without that, you'll get unexpected results reading the double in this example. You also have to worry a little bit about endianess if you want the file to be portably read on any other computer.

Comment: And if both the writing in python and the reading in C are done on the same computer, is endianess important? Are there like common types of endianess from which I can choose, or is it something set by the computer/OS/compiler...?

Comment: If it's only going to be used on one computer, not an issue. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Endianness for details.

Comment: Also, can you call f.write() multiple times, e.g. f.write(struct.pack('=i', 1)), f.write(struct.pack('=d', 5.0)), to make this file?

Comment: Sure, I guess so.

Comment: Just one more question please, can you not choose endianess in C? Is that why you used '=', as opposed to setting '<' in python for example, and using the same endinaess in C?